# Neural Network cost not going below certain value

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network

i'm trying to implement neural network in python  for classifying digits correctly. below is my code. the cost started out as 16000 and went down to 1600 and from there it is not able to go below.

any hints on how i can improve my neural network.

i'm not using bias and my learning rate is 0.01.

```
    from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
    digits=load_digits()
    X=digits.data
    y=digits.target

    #dgt_otpt is a 10x10 identity matrix 
    #dgt_otpt[0] output for the value 0
    #dgt_otpt[1] output for the value 1
    #dgt_otpt[2] output for the value 2
    #..
    #..
    #..
    #dgt_otpt[9] output for the value 9

    dgt_otpt=np.eye(10)

    #2 layer network 
    sizes=[len(X[0]),25,10]

    #weights
    weights=[np.random.rand(y,x) for x,y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]

    #sigmoid function
    def sg_fnc(z):
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

    #sigmoid derivative function
    def sg_fnc_drvtv(z):
        return sg_fnc(z)*(1-sg_fnc(z))

    n=0
    while n<10000:

        #calculating the cost of the network
        cst=0
        for i in zip (X,y):
            z1=np.dot(weights[0],i[0].reshape(64,1))
            hddn_lyr=sg_fnc(z1)

            z2=np.dot(weights[1],hddn_lyr)
            otpt_lyr=sg_fnc(z2)

            m=dgt_otpt[i[1]]
            m=m.reshape(10,1)

            cst+=np.sum((otpt_lyr-m)**2)

        print("interation:",n)
        print("cost:",cst)



        for i in zip (X,y):

            #feed forward
            z1=np.dot(weights[0],i[0].reshape(64,1))
            hddn_lyr=sg_fnc(z1)

            z2=np.dot(weights[1],hddn_lyr)
            otpt_lyr=sg_fnc(z2)

            m=dgt_otpt[i[1]]
            m=m.reshape(10,1)

            #backpropogation
            grd_dscnt_1=np.dot(2*(otpt_lyr-m)*sg_fnc_drvtv(z2),hddn_lyr.T)
            grd_dscnt_2=np.dot((np.dot(weights[1].T,2*(otpt_lyr-m)*sg_fnc_drvtv(z2))*sg_fnc_drvtv(z1)),i[0].reshape(1,64))

            weights[1]-=0.01*grd_dscnt_1
            weights[0]-=0.01*grd_dscnt_2

        n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Maleeha for your suggesting the standardization of data. i got the cost down to 3.something

below is my entire code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits=load_digits()
X=digits.data
y=digits.target
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
digit_scale=StandardScaler()
digit_data=digit_scale.fit_transform(X)
X=digit_data

#dgt_otpt is a 10x10 identity matrix 
#dgt_otpt[0] output for the value 0
#dgt_otpt[1] output for the value 1
#dgt_otpt[2] output for the value 2
#..
#..
#..
#dgt_otpt[9] output for the value 9

dgt_otpt=np.eye(10)

#2 layer network 
sizes=[len(X[0]),25,10]

#weights
weights=[np.random.rand(y,x) for x,y in zip(sizes[:-1],sizes[1:])]

#sigmoid function
def sg_fnc(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-z))

#sigmoid derivative function
def sg_fnc_drvtv(z):
    return sg_fnc(z)*(1-sg_fnc(z))

n=0
while n<10000:

    #calculating the cost of the network
    cst=0
    for i in zip (X,y):
        z1=np.dot(weights[0],i[0].reshape(64,1))
        hddn_lyr=sg_fnc(z1)

        z2=np.dot(weights[1],hddn_lyr)
        otpt_lyr=sg_fnc(z2)

        m=dgt_otpt[i[1]]
        m=m.reshape(10,1)

        cst+=np.sum((otpt_lyr-m)**2)

    print("interation:",n)
    print("cost:",cst)



    for i in zip (X,y):

        #feed forward
        z1=np.dot(weights[0],i[0].reshape(64,1))
        hddn_lyr=sg_fnc(z1)

        z2=np.dot(weights[1],hddn_lyr)
        otpt_lyr=sg_fnc(z2)

        m=dgt_otpt[i[1]]
        m=m.reshape(10,1)

        #backpropogation
        grd_dscnt_1=np.dot(2*(otpt_lyr-m)*sg_fnc_drvtv(z2),hddn_lyr.T)
        grd_dscnt_2=np.dot((np.dot(weights[1].T,2*(otpt_lyr-m)*sg_fnc_drvtv(z2))*sg_fnc_drvtv(z1)),i[0].reshape(1,64))

        weights[1]-=0.01*grd_dscnt_1
        weights[0]-=0.01*grd_dscnt_2

    n+=1
```